# Как развернуть макрос в шаблон

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

```
#define GET_ID(ID) ( ( ID ) >> 16 )
```

Comment: а зачем? Чем вас не устраивает это в виде макроса или в виде функции (сдвиг применим для очень ограниченного набора типов).

Comment: @pavel, `в виде функции` — причём шаблонной функции.

Comment: А если по хорошему — надо оформить сущность, в которой имеется подобный идентификатор, в класс и запрятать эту битовую магию внутрь метода (к примеру, `unsigned getId() const {return _packed >> 16;}`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <class I, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<I>>>
auto GET_ID(I value) -> decltype(value >> 16) {
    return value >> 16;
};
```

Пойдёт? :)

Comment: хорошо пойдёт )

Comment: А ещё лучше пойдёт замена `std::is_integral_v<>` на `std::is_unsigned_v<>`.

Comment: @Abyx как мне известно, в обобщённом коде пишут trailing return type для корректной работы SFINAE